# How to stretch Menu to entire window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2010, wpf application, including reference Dynamic data display maps.

first, that's how my project look :

[image]

I'm want to control the objects, the labels, especially on the *Toolbar*, I want the toolbar to be stretch for all the screen horizontal. it doesn't work.
the property horizontalAligment is "Stretch".
 dont know how to fix it.
there is my code in XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="MapSample.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
        Title="כוכב בוהק" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        d:DesignHeight="702"
        SizeToContent="Manual"
        d:DesignWidth="983"
        WindowState="Maximized" >


    <Grid Cursor="Hand"
          Height="704"
          Width="807">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="253*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="451*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Cursor="Hand"
              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
              Margin="0,0,12,185"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              Background="Gainsboro"
              FontWeight="Normal">
            <MenuItem Header="קובץ" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">

                <MenuItem  Name="Open"
                           Header="פתח">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                       פתח קובץ.
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem  Name="Save"
                           Header="שמור">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        שמור קובץ.
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem  Name="Options"
                           Header="הגדרות">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        הצג הגדרות.
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem  Name="Close"
                           Header="סגור">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        סגור תוכנית זו.
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="יצירה"
                      FontWeight="Bold"
                      FontSize="14">
                <MenuItem Header="יצירת גרפים" >
                                <MenuItem Name="CreatGraph"
                                          Header="גרף המציג זמן כפונקציה של דיוק" />
                                <MenuItem    Name="CreatGraph2"
                                             Header=" גרף המציג איכונים העוברים את המפרט מתוך כלל האיכונים שנורו" />
                                <MenuItem    Name="CreatGraph3"
                                             Header=" גרף המציג זמן כפונקציה של מרחק מהמכ'ם למסלול הירי" />
                                <MenuItem    Name="CreatGraph4"
                                             Header=" 'גרף המציג את גרף א' וגרף ג" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="יצירת מפות">
                    <MenuItem Name="CreatMap1"
                              Header="מפה שתציג נ'צ הנפילה האמיתית מול נ'צ נקודת חיתוך התצפיתנים והמרחק בינהם" />
                    <MenuItem    Name="CreatMap2"
                                 Header=" מפה שתכיל את המכ'ם, האיכון שהתקבל, מיקומי התצפיתנים והאזימוטים שלהם" />
                </MenuItem>

            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" Visible="-180,-90,360,180" Height="470" Width="700"
                         MouseLeftButtonDown="plotter_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                         MouseRightButtonDown="plotter_MouseRightButtonDown"
                         Margin="54,117"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2">


            <d3:ChartPlotter.DataTransform>
                <d3:MercatorTransform/>
            </d3:ChartPlotter.DataTransform>

            <d3:Map>
                <d3:OpenStreetMapServer/>           
            </d3:Map>

            <d3:CursorCoordinateGraph  Cursor="Pen"
                                       OpacityMask="Black" />
            <d3:AxisCursorGraph/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter>


        <Label Content=":תוצאות "
               Height="136"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="-160,118,0,0"
               Name="lbl_resualt_measurement"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="196"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
               Grid.RowSpan="2" />
        <Button Content="הכנס נקודה"
                Height="23"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="0,74,110,0"
                Name="btn_InsertPoint"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="78"
                Click="btn_insertPoint_Click"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed"
            Height="23"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="317,74,0,0"
                 Name="txt_Vertical"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="143"
                 Text="הכנס תחום בציר האנכי"
                 GotFocus="txt_Vertical_GotFocus"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox 
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Height="23"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="466,74,0,0"
                 Name="txt_Horizental"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="143"
                 Text="הכנס תחום בציר האופקי"
                 GotFocus="txt_Horizental_GotFocus"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Content=":אזימוטים מתקבלים "
               Height="86"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="-160,39,0,0"
               Name="lbl_Azimuth"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Width="201"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
        <Image Height="35"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="665,26,0,0"
               Name="PushPinImage"
               Stretch="Uniform"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="30"
               Source="/MapSample;component/Images/Push_Pin1.png"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="PushPinImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        <Image Height="35"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Margin="0,26,149,0"
               Name="PolygonImage"
               Stretch="Uniform"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="39"
               Source="/MapSample;component/Images/Maps-Polygon-icon.png"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="PolygonImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        <Image Height="35"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="572,26,0,0"
               Name="MesurmentImage"
               Stretch="Uniform"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="41"
               Source="/MapSample;component/Images/Mesurment.ico"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="MesurmentImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        <Image Height="40"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="524,24,0,0"
               Name="RadiusImage"
               Stretch="Uniform"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="42"
               Source="/MapSample;component/Images/CircleCR.png"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="RadiusImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't set Width property of Grid. And do you need Margin property of Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Menu` is stretched as much as it can. The limit is always set by the parent container.

In this case, your `Menu` is in a `Grid` which has an hardcoded width of `807` so your `Menu` won't get any wider than that.

Remove that constraint on your `Grid` and the menu will take stretch to the entire available space.

If you are used to HTML, it would be like having a `width: 100%` element in a `div` with `width: 807px`. The inner element can't stretch beyond the parent's limits.

Comment: I thought about it too but when I move the Munu to the Window it type error : " The property Content is set more than once."

Comment: Don't move the menu to the `Window`, remove the `Width` property on the `Grid` instead.

Comment: Thanks. it works. but i cannot control on the other thins on the wpf, I got crazy from this its not comfortable, do you have any advice ? the toolbar fixed, but i cannot move the map, it type that it only read and connot move, and i cannot control on the labels and images.

Comment: You can put a grid within a grid if you need to constraint other elements. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but if you have another question start a new one and you'll get a better answer there than in a comment discussion.